# Windows prompting for username and password

Tags: python, apache, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm setting my mysql info in my app.py file:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://root:[PASSWORD]@localhost/survey'
```

Python reloads the app.py file just fine, but when I hit the server in the browser, it's prompting me for a username and password. However when I enter in my credentials, it's coming up as Unauthorized Access. Am I missing anything?

[image]

This is Python/Flask/Flask-SQLAlchemy running on Windows Server 2008 R2, running Apache.

Comment: are you using any sort of basic auth in the rest of your code?

Comment: Are you using an http server or just Flask's development server? The message appears to be related to that, and unrelated to your database.

Comment: @James_Parsons not that I'm aware of.

Comment: I've noticed if I change my password in the file to an incorrect one, I do not get the login prompt. Instead I get an access denied mysql related error.

Answer (score 1):

Your apache settings may be blocking access for non-authenticated users. You should check your apache settings for any `AuthBasic` settings. Else there may be an `.htaccess` that is read by apache somewhere, blocking your requests.

Comment: I'm assuming this is it. I just can't figure out where/what it's hitting that is causing this.